# multi-master replication and consensus protocols in GridDB

Tags: database, griddb

When using GridDB in highly distributed environment:

- How does the use of multi-master replication, and consensus protocols, affect the data consistency?
- What mechanisms are used to ensure these properties, under different network and workload conditions?

I am reading the documentations, but if I can get some experienced discussion on this.